# How can I block URLs ending with ".pdf" in a PAC file? `shExpMatch()` doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, pac

#### Context

I’m deploying a [Proxy Auto-Config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) (PAC) file through [JAMF MDM](https://www.jamf.com/) using the auto global HTTP proxy. The purpose of this file is to block some traffic on the network level. We’re deploying the PAC files on iPhones.

I tried to block all URLs ending with `.pdf` by using [`shExpMatch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file#shexpmatch):

`shExpMatch(url, “.*pdf”)`

But iOS seems to just skip that line without implementing it. Am I doing something wrong or is there an apple specific function that I should use?

Here is my full code:

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    host = host.toLowerCase();
    if (
       url.match(".pdf")
    || shExpMatch(url, ".*pdf")
    || _dnsDomainIs(host, "api.giphy.com")
    ) {
    // deny this request
    return blackhole;

    } else {
    return normal;
    }
}
```

##### Question

- How can I block any link ending with ".pdf" using a PAC file on IOS?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.